# Prevent PDF Download in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

Is there any way to prevent PDF download and printing option from browser ?
I am using PHP codeigniter for uploading the PDF file from admin side. I want to restrict the download access, inspect access, page source access from user side. Users only need to read the PDF.

So is there any way to do this using PHP or Javascript?

Users can take screenshots, which is not a problem. I only wan't to prevent the pdf url and download access in all aspects.
Do we have to convert PDF to any other format for this?

Comment: Highly doubt it since it needs to be downloaded onto the machine to be viewed... In the PDF itself you can disable printing if I remember right.

Comment: Why go through the trouble of this? Spend 20 hours of programming to maybe prevent this, and then somebody will figure out they can just screenshot the whole thing. This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: To take screenshot is not an issue. We just wanted to prevent the access of pdf url and download button. Any solution?